# Can't picker Imageview2 in uiImageViewPickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

i'm using the 4 `UIImageView` with `UIImagePickerController`. I want I use camera to take photo its present in imageview 1 and retake photo again I want to show in imageview 2 but the problem is if I retake the photo again also showing in Imageview1 only.

here my code

```
 @IBOutlet weak var CameraOutlet: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var Complaint_Image1: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var Complaint_Image2: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var Complaint_Image3: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var Complaint_Image4: UIImageView!

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let picture = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    Complaint_Image1.image = picture

    if Complaint_Image1 != nil {
        Complaint_Image2.image = picture
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic should be:

1. If image1.image has no image, then set that image
2. Otherwise, set image2.image.

These lines:

```
Complaint_Image1.image = picture

if Complaint_Image1 != nil {
    Complaint_Image2.image = picture
}
```

should be

```
if Complaint_Image1.image != nil {
    Complaint_Image2.image = picture
} else {
    Complaint_Image1.image = picture
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro Its Work Fine now